# why free(ptr) here is not suggested approach?

Tags: c

```
int x = 2;
int* ptr = &x;
free(ptr); //why is this an undefined behavior
```

`free` will deallocate the memory. here `*ptr` holds the address of `x`. Now if it `free(ptr)` the ptr pointing to `x` is no more. But iam having confusion if this is not a right approach

Comment: You didn't allocate it, so you can't free it.

Comment: Basic rule of thumb, every `(m|c|re)alloc` must eventually be followed by a `free`, unless you have legitimate reasons not to.

Answer (score 2):

To use `free()`, it is important to only free items which have come from `malloc()` or `calloc()` (or reprocessed by `realloc()`).  Those (along with *free()*) manage the [heap](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Memory_management#HEAP).

```
int *p = malloc (5620);   /* allocate 5620 bytes */

   /* do something with memory at p */
   ....

free (p);
```

While other pointers match the data type of *free()* that is not sufficient. To *free* a pointer not from *malloc()* is practically guaranteed to cause serious trouble:  immediately crashing the program, introducing a subtle bug which causes weird results later, or clobbers something unrelated.

The [*heap*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Memory_management#HEAP) is one or more areas of the process's memory which provides space to dynamically allocate many types and instances of objects.  Those areas do not have to be associated to a particular program variable; linked lists, trees, graphs, and other data structures are naturally held in the heap.

Comment: Or `realloc()`.

Comment: Just multiply `5260` by itself a few times and see what `malloc`ing that gets you :)

Comment: The link you have added in your post is referring to **heap data structure**. I believe, you mean this - [heap](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Memory_management#HEAP).

Comment: @H.S.:  Thanks, updated.

Answer (score 1):

`x` here is defined on the stack, not the heap. you didn't allocate the memory explicitly with `malloc` or related functions, so there's no need to `free`.

Comment: Not only is there no need to `free`, attempting to `free` it has undefined behavior (is likely to mess up the implementation's internal data structures).

Answer (score 0):

In C, objects can have automatic ("stack"), static (global), thread-local, or allocated storage. The last type, allocated storage, is obtained by `malloc` and its lifetime is not tied to execution of a particular block/function (one instance per live call), the lifetime of a thread (one instance per live thread), or global (one instance, period), but rather lives until you explicitly deallocate it by passing a pointer to it to `free`. The `free` function can only be used with objects having allocated storage; passing any other pointer to it yields undefined behavior. And passing pointer to other types of objects would not make sense, as their lifetimes are bound to other things and cannot be arbitrarily ended.